# How do I generate a set of four specific characters?

Tags: python, string, character, generator

New to coding, having fun with an adventure game. I want the character to be able to run away from a monster and in doing so, the game will generate a random character that must be one of the following four characters:

N S W E

I am having trouble doing so, currently I have

```
import random
import string

x=random.randint(4,13)
a=string.ascii_letters[x]
print(a)
```

The issue here is my understanding of the .randint. It generates any number BETWEEN the 2 variables given. I need a function (which I cannot seem to find) to generate specific random numbers of my choosing. The random numbers I need are 4, 13, 18 and 22. These correspond to E N S W in the range of letters.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `random.choice('NSEW')`.

Comment: thank you, I searched for hours trying to find this simple syntax!

Comment: You should read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice .  It is literally right next to `randint`.

Comment: whats sad is I read that page several times and missed this, I thought HOW CAN THERE NOT BE a way to do this in one line!